# I am getting java.util.EmptyStackException in an if-else loop. Where is the stack implementation going wrong?

Tags: java, stack

Below is a java code which accepts an expression String in infix format and converts it into postfix format.

```
package post;
import java.util.Stack;

public class InfixtoPostfix 
{
  void convert(String expression)
  {
    Stack<Character> st=new Stack<Character>();
    char c;char p;char e;
    int pr;int f;
    int flag1=0;
    String result=new String();
    int i=0;
    int len=expression.length();
    while(len>0)
    {
       if(expression.charAt(i)!='+'&&expression.charAt(i)!='-'&&expression.charAt(i)!='*'&&expression.charAt(i)!='/')
       {
            result=result+(String.valueOf(expression.charAt(i)));
       }
       else if(expression.charAt(i)=='(')
       {
           st.push(expression.charAt(i));
       }
       else if(expression.charAt(i)==')')
       {

            c=st.pop();
            while((st.size()>0) || (c!='('))
            {
                result=result+c;
                c=st.pop();
            }
        }


   else if(expression.charAt(i)=='+'||expression.charAt(i)=='-'||expression.charAt(i)=='*'||expression.charAt(i)=='/')
   {
                c=expression.charAt(i);
                p=st.pop();
                pr=precedence(c,p);
                if(pr==0)
                {

                    result=result+p;
                    st.push(c);


                }
                else
                {
                    st.push(p);
                    st.push(c);

                }



    }


len--;i++;       
    }


    System.out.println(result);   
}



int precedence(char op1,char op2)
{
  int b=0;
  if((op1=='+'||op1=='-')&&(op2=='*'||op2=='/'))
  {
    b=0;
  }
  else if(op1=='*' && op2=='/')
  {
    b=0;
  } 
  else if(op1=='/' && op2=='*')
  {
    b=1;
  }
  else if(op1=='+' && op2=='-')
  {
    b=1;
  }
  else if(op1=='+' && op2=='-')
  {
    b=1;
  }
return b;
}


    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        InfixtoPostfix object=new InfixtoPostfix();
        object.convert("4+3*7-5");
    }

}
```

Following code section from above entire code when commented, no error is encountered. When this particular code section is un-commented then  java.util.EmptyStackException error occurs:

What wrong in the stack implementation is going on in this below code section ?

```
else if(expression.charAt(i)=='+'||expression.charAt(i)=='- '||expression.charAt(i)=='*'||expression.charAt(i)=='/')
   {
                c=expression.charAt(i);
                p=st.pop();
                pr=precedence(c,p);
                if(pr==0)
                {

                    result=result+p;
                    st.push(c);


                }
                else
                {
                    st.push(p);
                    st.push(c);

                }



    }
```

Comment: the solution is simple, don't pop() unless you know there are some items left i.e check the size() before you pop.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is at this line:

```
p = st.pop();
```

the stack is still empty when you try to pop an element, there are two ways to resolve it: as @Ousmane Mahy Diaw suggest, you could put an if before the pop method:

```
else if (expression.charAt(i) == '+' || expression.charAt(i) == '-' || expression.charAt(i) == '*' || expression.charAt(i) == '/') {
                c = expression.charAt(i);
                if (!st.isEmpty()) {
                    p = st.pop();
                    pr = precedence(c, p);
                    if (pr == 0) {

                        result = result + p;
                        st.push(c);

                    } else {
                        st.push(p);
                        st.push(c);

                    }
                }
            }
```

This conducts to this out: 
    System.out.println(result); //4375 Which is not correcto for the evaluation of 4+3*7-5

The second approach is: put an element in the stack before to pop them, it depends on the logic of your algorithm and your needs, here is a solution that you could check for your logic:

[Java string-type equation double digit value issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42817854/java-string-type-equation-double-digit-value-issue/42823765#42823765)